# Debian 8: Restarting apache2 failed

Tags: php, apache, debian-jessie

I'm trying to Configure timezone for PHP and after setting  that, I have a set of commands to execute provided,

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load .
ln -s ../mods-available/headers.load .
ln -s ../mods-available/expires.load .
ln -s ../mods-available/ssl.load .
ln -s ../mods-available/ssl.conf .
ln -s ../mods-available/php5* .
ln -s ../mods-available/socache_shmcb.load .

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

When I run the last command with `sudo`, I get the following error,

```
[....] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

When I type in the terminal,

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

I get the output of,

```
​● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-08 12:57:08 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 23298 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23587 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What should I do in this case?

`Upadte`

The output of the command of `sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` is provided,

```
​[Fri Dec 08 11:58:17.392972 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12892:tid 140108409681792] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:17.393055 2017] [core:notice] [pid 12892:tid 140108409681792] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:36.585248 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12892:tid 140108409681792] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:36.588582 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12892:tid 140108409681792] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:36.588590 2017] [core:notice] [pid 12892:tid 140108409681792] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:39.747035 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12892:tid 140108409681792] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:40.816350 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15087] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:40.816435 2017] [core:notice] [pid 15087] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:42.228275 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15087] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:43.344556 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15186] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 08 11:58:43.344605 2017] [core:notice] [pid 15186] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Dec 08 12:40:45.121960 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15186] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down​
```

The output of command `/usr/sbin/apache2` is provided,

```
[Fri Dec 08 13:30:36.877713 2017] [core:warn] [pid 23750] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Dec 08 13:30:36.879775 2017] [core:warn] [pid 23750] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Fri Dec 08 13:30:36.879827 2017] [core:warn] [pid 23750] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Fri Dec 08 13:30:36.879865 2017] [core:warn] [pid 23750] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Fri Dec 08 13:30:36.879905 2017] [core:warn] [pid 23750] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: No such file or directory​
```

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl status apache2.service` ?

Comment: Updated the question with output, have a look

Comment: What's the output of running `apache` or `apache2` from cli?

Comment: Not 100% clear what the problem is from that but if it helps, you shouldn't really be running the `ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load` commands to enable modules, you can just run, for example `a2enmod rewrite`.

Comment: Could you please write in details? I'm have next to nothing experience with `Linux`

Comment: Could you please write in details? I'm have next to nothing experience with Linux. If I just out that in the `cmd`, I get the command is not found

Comment: Try running `apache` or `apache2` as a command

Comment: I get the command not found for both key words

Comment: How about `httpd`

Comment: The same command not found

Comment: Okay, can you paste the output of `sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: So, instead of: `ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load .` You would be safer running `a2enmod rewrite`, instead of `ln -s ../mods-available/headers.load .` you would be safer running `a2enmod headers`, instead of both `ln -s ../mods-available/ssl.load .` and `ln -s ../mods-available/ssl.conf .`, run `a2enmod ssl` etc. Does that follow?

Comment: Check the updated question

Comment: Also, post the output of `/usr/sbin/apache2` please.

Comment: Try `/usr/sbin/apache2` cmd and post the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160792/discussion-between-arefe-and-motomod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't properly enabled the PHP 5 module by the looks of it. Try running `a2enmod php5`, if it fails you might not have the module installed, in which case try: `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` and then `a2enmod php5` again.

Comment: The `a2enmod` command not found error. I have tried to `apt-get install` and nothing installed or upgraded

Comment: Super harsh, can you try `apt-get install apache2.4-common` and then re-run the command?

Comment: Unable to locate the package `apache2.4-common`

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install apache2.4-common`?